# Creating an Invoice with LineItemRef does not automatically fill the line item description

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

When we try to create an invoice with a Line Item Ref without providing the line item description, QBO doesn't prefill the product description as line item description. I have checked the same via APIExplorer and confirmed the behaviour.

Here's a sample Create Request XML:

```
<Invoice xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
  <Line>
    <Amount>15</Amount>
    <DetailType>SalesItemLineDetail</DetailType>
    <SalesItemLineDetail>
      <ItemRef>36</ItemRef>
    </SalesItemLineDetail>
  </Line>
  <CustomerRef>378</CustomerRef>
</Invoice>
```

Is there anyway we can ask the QBO to prefill the description for line item if no description field is specified as part of the create request?

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, It is not possible. You need to explicitly set description value.

Thanks